# Png turns to unexpected strings

Tags: html, webserver, favicon

I have a problem with using icon as png. Here is the example:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="/favicon-192.png">
```

[But result is something weird](https://negdoor.mn/favicon-192.png)

Anybody explain me ?

Comment: Your webserver seems to not transmit the proper MIME type with the image. It should be `image/png`, but is `document/html`. See the network tab in your browsers dev tools for details

Comment: I saw network tab but type is `webp`

Comment: My Firefox dev tools show `text/html` as mime type. If I wget from some server without giving a navigator user agent string it says `application/json`. @batgerel.e You should definetely check your NGinx config